# Unable to get subsites of sharepoint web applicaton

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have a sharepoint web application, with two subsites "test1" and "test2".

[image]
I am trying to get the subsites using classes from Microsoft.SharePoint.Client namespace.

```
var context = new ClientContext(string.Format("http://{0}", "www05:48042"));

context.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(credentials.Login, credentials.Password);
var sites = context.Web.Webs;
context.Load(sites);

context.ExecuteQuery();
```

Login and password are correct. However, I am always getting an empty collection in webs, but should get at least 2 elements.
What am I doing wrong? Any suggestions?

Comment: But those are not subsites, instead those are two different site collections

Comment: and AFAIK, client context does not expose objects like `SPWebApplication`

Comment: I tried it, it is also empty.

Answer (score 1):

Those are not subsites instead they are different site collections

> Pages are what you actually see and use on SharePoint. A Site is a collection of pages. A SiteCollection is, as the name indicates, a collection of sites. A WebApplication is a collection of SiteCollections.

and AFAIK, client context does not expose objects like `SPWebApplication`, you can try PowerShell though:

```
Get-SPSite -limit all -WebApplication http://yourWebapplicationUrl | Ft -autosize -wrap | Out-File -FilePath "PathToYourFile"
```